# Unable to deploy iOS app on iPhone running iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated Xcode version to 12.3 but still Xcode complains about unable to connect to iPhone
. Any help would be much appreciated.

Device: iPhone Xr
iOS version: 14.3
Xcode version: 12.3

Comment: two things u need to do , restart your and restart your xcode and check

Comment: typo mistake : restart your phone and restart your xcode

Answer (score 0):

Restarting  my iPhone did the trick.